Use chart.js version 4.4.2 in Vue3 project get error
use import { Chart } from "chart.js/auto"; in JavaScript file then console report a error:
GET http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chart__js_auto.js?v=2ebd765d net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Outdated Optimize Dep)

trying to use .js file but it work different from npm install version.
so i can't use file verison

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is probably a cache issue associated with vite.
This might help you:

Modify your vite.config.js file like so:

import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  ...
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['chart.js/auto']
  }
});


Delete your node_modules/.vite/ folder
Reinstall packages + and try again

Also check out https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#browser-cache
